# FSharp.Data: Transform multiple columns to a single column (dictionary result)

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am using `FSharp.Data` to transform HTML table data, i.e.

```
type RawResults = HtmlProvider<url>

let results = RawResults.Load(url).Tables
for row in results.Table1.Rows do
    printfn " %A " row
```

Example output:

```
("Model: Generic", "Submit Date: July 22, 2016")
("Gene: Sequencing Failed", "Exectime: 5 hrs. 21 min.")
~~~ hundreds of more rows ~~~~
```

I am trying to split those "two column"-based elements into a single column sequence to eventually get to a dictionary result.

Desired dictionary key:value result:

```
["Model", Generic]
["Submit Date", July 22, 2016]
["Gene", "Sequencing Failed"]
~~~~
```

How can you iter (or split?) the two columns (`Column1` & `Column2`) to pipe both of those individual columns to produce a dictionary result?

```
let summaryDict = 
    results.Table1.Rows 
    |> Seq.skip 1
    |> Seq.iter (fun x -> x.Column1 ......
    |> ....
```

Comment: Does the original table data repeat in the same format with two rows of data for each result?

Comment: @TheInnerLight Each `row in results.Table1.Rows` produces an element like: `("Model: Generic", "Submit Date: July 22, 2016")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in `string` API to split over the `:`. I usually prefer to wrap `String.Split` in curried form:

```
let split (separator : string) (s : string) = s.Split (separator.ToCharArray ())
```

Additionally, while not required, when working with two-element tuples, I often find it useful to define a helper module with functions related to this particular data structure. You can put various functions in such a module (e.g. `curry`, `uncurry`, `swap`, etcetera), but in this case, a single function is all you need:

```
module Tuple2 =
    let mapBoth f g (x, y) = f x, g y
```

With these building blocks, you can easily split each tuple element over `:`, as shown in this FSI session:

```
> [
    ("Model: Generic", "Submit Date: July 22, 2016")
    ("Gene: Sequencing Failed", "Exectime: 5 hrs. 21 min.") ]
|> List.map (Tuple2.mapBoth (split ":") (split ":"));;

val it : (string [] * string []) list =
  [([|"Model"; " Generic"|], [|"Submit Date"; " July 22, 2016"|]);
   ([|"Gene"; " Sequencing Failed"|], [|"Exectime"; " 5 hrs. 21 min."|])]
```

At this point, you still need to strip leading whitespace, as well as convert the arrays into your desired format, but I trust you can take it from here (otherwise, please ask).

Comment: Thanks!... the `Tuple2.mapBoth` does not play well with `seq<HtmlProvider<...>.Table.Row>`` due to type inference but some heavy handed type conversions got me there with your example.